# How to fix 'Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]'?

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pyodbc

I can't connect MSsql database to django.

When I trying to do with python, It works well, but when I try to run server on Django I get error.

Pyodbc version : 4.0.27;
Django version : 2.1.13;
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64).

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '<djangoBanks>',
        'HOST': '<DESKTOP-0FKB14V>',
        'USER': '<test>',
        'PASSWORD': '<12345>',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
            'Trusted_Connection' : 'Yes',
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run `python manage.py runserver` I get this error:

> '08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named
>   Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].  (53)
>   (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
>   Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
>   for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   (53)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited 'Options' and then it started work.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'djangoBanks',
        'HOST': 'DESKTOP-0FKB14V',
        'USER': 'test',
        'PASSWORD': '12345',

    'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
            'SERVER' : 'DESKTOP-0FKB14V',
            'DATABASE' : 'djangoBanks',
            'UID' : 'test',
            'PWD' : '12345',
            'Trusted_Connection' : 'Yes',
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In my case, Name pipes is disabled in SQL Server Configurations Manager, Afer enabling everything works fine